# How to get URL to uploaded file?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am successfully uploading files to S3.

However I am having trouble trying to get the URL of the file that was uploaded.

I see there is a getKey method, but it does not seem to work as I thought.

Essentially I am trying to replace the name of the file listed with a link to the uploaded file.  Useless uploading a file if the person uploading cannot get a link to it.

So I have been trying to get the URL or key of the uploaded object, and have been planning on modifying the filename text in the 'complete' event.

Perhaps there is a better way to modify the final filename text.

Here is what I does not seem to work:

```
    }).on('complete', function (event, id, name, responseJSON) {

    // Fails, not using the fineuploader object correctly, manualuploader is the fineuploader object.
    console.log("Object Key:+manualuploader.getKey(id));

    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. Obtain a signed URL for the file via the AWS SDK server-side and return the URL in your response to Fine Uploader's uploadSuccess request.  It will be made available to your "complete" event handler via the response param.
2. Construct the URL client-side using the key and bucket URL.

You must use option 1 if your file is not publicly viewable.  The demo on fineuploader.com uses option 1.  In most cases, this is the most appropriate approach, unless you are ok allowing anyone to stream the files from your bucket as much as they want forever.

Also, if you are trying to call the `getKey` method, or any other method, on a Fine Uploader instance when using the jQuery plug-in, you must do so [as described in the jQuery plug-in documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/jquery.html).  Your call to the `getKey` method in your code above is not consistent with the documentation.  You would need to call getKey like this: `$("#uploader").fineUploaderS3("getKey", id)`.

Comment: Hello Ray, thank you for the quick response.  I unfortunately am still having a small problem.  I am trying to find the full JSON response sent back by the server, however I am only seeing a simple 'success: true' entity, when handling the 'complete' event and looking at the JSONresponse variable.

Comment: I do see in some of the debug output going to the console that an HTML response seems to have been captured, that does indeed include a full URL, in fact I see that the PHP handler on my server is setup to return the 'templink' like the fineuploader sample.  So, I just can't seem to get my hands on the right response JSON, thanks for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't be returning HTML.  You must return JSON as a response to the upload success POST request.  Have a look at the S3 PHP demo code, which is used on fineuploader.com to return the link to the client from the server.  If you follow this example, it will work.  Print out the contents of the response param to the console, or examine it in the javascript debugger of your choice.  If you don't see the property you are expecting, look at the HTTP traffic and re-examine your server-side code.

Comment: Which permissions would I be missing?

Comment: POST http://typhooncloud.com/fineuploader/s3handler.php?success HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Type: text/html

<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\AccessDeniedException: AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, Status Code: 403, AWS Request ID: 2D529E5D8FC68856, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: Access Denied, User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.4.6 Guzzle/3.7.3 curl/7.19.7 PHP/5.3.24
  thrown in <b>/home/content/68/8770868/html/fineuploader/aws/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php</b> on line <b>91</b><br />

Comment: Console after this response also outputs: [FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Upload success was acknowledged by the server.

Comment: The PHP script I am using is from your example: * PHP Server-Side Example for Fine Uploader S3.

Comment: The IAM user associated with whatever keys you are passing to AWS with that server-side call does not have the appropriate permissions.  If you are using the client-side keys, that is your problem.  You will need another set of keys tied to an IAM user with appropriate privileges.  The simplest solution would be to use the admin template when creating an IAM group/user.